# adding legend in pcolor with cs.cmap.set_under and .set_over

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, colorbar

I have googled how to set legends in matplotlib pcolor, but I am still unsure and have not found references to how to set a legend for the specific colors I have set to `.set_under` and `.set_over`
Is this possible to have a legend and a colorbar in this case?  Since I have done `cmap.set_under(1)` for example, this means I have set the colorbar to show a different range than the legend (which I have still yet to figure out how to add).

I have found an example here on https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_masked.html  which I have reduced a bit to better explain my question:

```
from copy import copy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

x0, x1 = -5, 5
y0, y1 = -3, 3
x = np.linspace(x0, x1, 500)
y = np.linspace(y0, y1, 500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10*(Z2 - Z1)

cmap = copy(plt.cm.gray)
cmap.set_over('r', 1.0)
cmap.set_under('g', 1.0)
cmap.set_bad('b', 1.0)
Zm = np.ma.masked_where(Z > 1.2, Z)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(Zm, interpolation='bilinear',
                cmap=cmap,
                norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0),
                aspect='auto',
                origin='lower',
                extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1])

############
### Here a title is used instead of a legend
ax.set_title('Green=low, Red=high, Blue=masked')
### instead of a set_title above, I would like it to be a legend 
############
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, extend='both')

plt.show()
```

In this example, there is a set title to explain the out-of-bounds colors. However, instead of a title as above, I would like it to be a legend.

Comment: Can you use a [mcve] to explain your issue? (I guess Basemap is not needed here, but some data which you'd use to explain the desired output.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I found an example here https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_masked.html  .. They just put what what the out of bound color values mean in the Title of the figure, and did not have a legend.  I can do it this way .  I will try in the future to do a better job at providing sample data

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ok I have edited my question becuase it is still not answered and the title is a workaround to the legend. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define your own legend with `Rectangle`s colorized as the over, under and bad values previously set to the colormap.

```
rect = lambda color: plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=color)
legend = ax.legend([rect("r"), rect("g"), rect("b")], ["high","low","masked"])
```

[image]